# SMS not sending to new contacts in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms, smart-capture, cloudpagesurl

I am hearing that new contacts will not receive SMS because they have not gone through Mobile Connect. Adding a +1 will help them receive the message, is there a way to auto fill a +1 in a smart capture form?

Comment: Could you explain what this `+1` is or does? How are you sending the SMS? If you're sending from Journey Builder, please share what you are choosing in the "Delivery Options" configuration step in the "Confirm subscriber Opt-in section"

Comment: +1 is the country code. If the number is not yet present in Mobile Connect it doesn't have the Locale if it has just been created as a new salesforce record. Opt in: subscribe all contacts to a keyword. They are opting in on a form then having an account created then moving through journey builder

Answer (score 0):

Since it's transitioning through Core, you can create a Formula field where you add the country code based on the country. Sync this field with SFMC and create it with the Phone datatype in your DE.

Also, if the `phonenumber` is prefixed with the country code, there is no need to add a `Locale` field if you are using Journey Builder for the sendings.